# Law and its formula that says: more time organism working the slower (or less precise) the movements

Tags: cognitive-psychology, neuroscience, cognitive-neuroscience, cognitive-modeling, behaviorism

What is the name of the law and the equation that says that "the more time an organism is working the slower (or less precise) its movements." ?

I read once that there is a law in behavioral science that says that: "The more an organism is doing something(working) the slower its movements are (or less precise, can't remember exactly).". That law also has equation that describes it. I need to know the name of that law.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague, but it sounds like you might be looking for [Hick's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hick%27s_law).  Hick's law states the relationship between the number of possible responses that an organism can provide for a given task and the minimum time necessary to engage a response.

You may have also been thinking of one of the [computational models for two-alternative forced-choice tasks (2AFC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-alternative_forced_choice#Computational_models_of_decision_making_in_2AFC).

Let me know if any of this rings a bell!